# How to avoid empty spaces of directory while installing assemblies?

Tags: c#, cmd, .net-assembly, gac

I am trying to install an assembly in GAC through command prompt. But unfortunately, my assembly is located in location with folder names with spaces. So command prompt could not recognize the command properly.

Below is my command

```
gacutil /i C:\\Users\\amalraj.umapathy\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\WindowsFormsApplication17\\WindowsFormsApplication17\\bin\\Debug\\AutomationAssemblies\\4.0\\Automation.dll"
```

Please help me resolve the issues.

Thanks and Regards,
Amal Raj

Comment: Why do you have a closing quote `"` but no opening one?

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
gacutil /i "C:\Users\amalraj.umapathy\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication17\WindowsFormsApplication17\bin\Debug\AutomationAssemblies\4.0\Automation.dll"
```

Note the use of " for the path and the removal of \\